# catkin build in Ubuntu 20.04 noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the answer is in an issue linked below, and that catkin tools isn't ready for noetic yet, and I'll have to test and upgrade my packages using catkin_make.

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-catkin-tools : Depends: python3-trollius but it is not installable
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install python3-trollius
...
E: Package 'python3-trollius' has no installation candidate
```

Try pip instead:

```
sudo pip3 install -U catkin_tools
Collecting catkin_tools
  Downloading catkin_tools-0.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (379 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 379 kB 4.4 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from catkin_tools) (45.2.0)
Collecting osrf-pycommon>0.1.1
  Downloading osrf_pycommon-0.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting trollius
  Downloading trollius-2.1.post2.tar.gz (274 kB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 274 kB 24.9 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: catkin-pkg>0.2.9 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from catkin_tools) (0.4.20)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyYAML in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from catkin_tools) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from trollius->catkin_tools) (1.14.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: trollius
  Building wheel for trollius (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for trollius: filename=trollius-2.1.post2-py3-none-any.whl size=122060 sha256=c84ada60b3e737fefbf018b65fc9889526a61e9d1fe663c76b1ebdeaed9adc45
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f4/64/34/347c23c361a3e52dd29b82cbe7ca542769f85d9b7aef4f764c
Successfully built trollius

Installing collected packages: osrf-pycommon, trollius, catkin-tools
Successfully installed catkin-tools-0.4.5 osrf-pycommon-0.1.9 trollius-2.1.post2
```

The github issue mentions trollius should be replaced by asyncio, so seeing trollius above isn't encouraging.

```
~/catkin_ws$ catkin build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin", line 5, in <module>
    from catkin_tools.commands.catkin import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 28, in <module>
    from catkin_tools.common import is_tty
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catkin_tools/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    import trollius as asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/base_events.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import tasks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/tasks.py", line 565
    def async(coro_or_future, loop=None):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That leads to: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/pull/574 , then to https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/597

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353113/catkin-build-in-ubuntu-20.04-noetic?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-24**:
Then what I recommend in my comment should work for you as well.

I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: as of 2020-12-25, it may be easier to make sure you have the ROS package repositories configured (the same ones you use to install ROS itself), and then:

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools python3-osrf-pycommon
```

The `osrf-pycommon` package is a dependency, but not in the Debian control file, hence it doesn't get installed automatically.

Note: this is still a work-around of sorts, as the main problem has not been addressed yet.

---

Original answer: are you trying to do this on Ubuntu Focal or Bionic? If you "only" have Python 3, then I believe [catkin/catkin_tools#597](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/597) should not matter: on Focal, `catkin_tools` would be running using Python 3, so that would be the same interpreter as it should use in the workspace itself. The issue describes a situation where there is a difference between the interpreter running `catkin_tools` vs the interpreter used in the workspace.

As to Trollius: there just hasn't been a release yet of `catkin_tools` with the PRs integrated which remove the dependency.

I'd suggest to try and install `catkin_tools` using `pip`, but from the repository (so not a released version):

```
pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git
```

This works for me.

Note: be sure to remove this work-around after a new release of `catkin_tools` has been cut. Otherwise you will run into issues later.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2020-05-24**:
It's 20.04 focal (updated title)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2020-06-06**:
It looks like the pip github install is no longer needed

```
pip3 uninstall catkin_tools
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools
catkin build
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-06**:
This was recently fixed with the release of `0.7.0` afaik.

**Comment by [viktor.holova](https://answers.ros.org/users/51651/viktor.holova/) on 2020-06-16**:
Looks like, as of today, there is still work going on to get 0.7.0 fully working in python3 IF you would like to install with `sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools`. That is, I am experiencing `'osrf-pycommon>0.1.1' distribution was not found` if I install with `sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools` and try to run any `catkin` commands. See https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594#issuecomment-644241926

So as of today, seems working solution is still:

`pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git`

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2020-10-23**:
this worked for me:
`sudo apt-get install python3-osrf-pycommon python3-catkin-tools`
credits: based on mintar comment on : https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594

**Comment by [aleena_infinitynbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44647/aleena_infinitynbeyond/) on 2020-12-25**:
Thanks, this worked for me pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git in ROS Noetic

**Comment by [OrnellaT](https://answers.ros.org/users/70672/ornellat/) on 2021-03-29**:
Thanks, `catkin build` works for me after `sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools python3-osrf-pycommon` in ROS Noetic with Ubuntu 20.04

**Comment by [enricovilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/76467/enricovilla/) on 2021-06-22**:
I installed catkin-tools with `sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools python3-osrf-pycommon` and after that `catkin build` works fine for me. When I do `source devel/setup.bash` my workspace is not added to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, while if a I do the same with a workspace build through `catkin_make` everything it work fine. Does someone had the same issue?

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-07-09**:
@enricovilla I did the same thing and worked fine for me with `catkin build`. (I am running ROS noetic)